# Toggling mobile data with tasker doesn't work, even with "write secure settings" enabled (Android 10)

Tags: tasker

I'm on a UleFone Armor X7 (cheap waterproof/rugged thing) running Android 10.  I'm trying to use Tasker to conserve power for multi-day bike rides with no charging*, and one thing I'd like to do is turn off as much communication as possible for several minutes, then on briefly to pick up messages, then off again in a loop.

I know aeroplane mode requires root (edit: or ADB Wifi), and I don't want to lose Google Pay, but I should be able to toggle mobile data without it according to the following screenshot:

[image]

This says either root, or ADB WiFi, or Write Secure Settings should be enough.  ADB WiFi isn't an option, because it needs a PC at every boot, which is incompatible with turning the phone off overnight - to save power.  So I've installed ADB, [granted the permission](https://tasker.joaoapps.com/userguide/en/help/ah_secure_setting_grant.html), and it still doesn't work. I can test that the permission is set: `adb shell dumpsys package net.dinglisch.android.taskerm |grep SECURE_SETTINGS` returns `android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS: granted=true` but when I try to test the task I get

```
Error: 1
Couldn't toggle mobile data on this device
```

I suspect a semantic error, meaning that ((ADB Wifi *or* root) *and* (Write secure settings)) is needed. [Enabling ADB Wifi](https://tasker.joaoapps.com/userguide/en/help/ah_adb_wifi.html) does indeed allow Tasker to toggle aeroplane mode - but while Tasker can keep ADB Wifi alive (even apparently with Wifi itself off), this doesn't persist over a reboot, such as shutting down overnight to save battery, and a PC is needed again on restart.  Enabling battery save mode overnight may be an option.

I'm thinking of trying [something with AutoInput](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/183030/44734), but I'm not keen, as it (i) requires the screen to be unlocked, and (ii) can on toggle, not set a state. I also don't want to pay even a little (on principle) to test something with these issues.

I've seen a few similar questions for very old Android versions, but nothing recent.

---

* I will have an external battery, and a dynamo, but just assume they're not enough to keep everything charged, especially as I navigate on my phone.

Comment: Yes, thanks @beeshyams. I'm editing the Q now so we'll be able to tidy these comments soon

Comment: I don't use Tasker, so can't be very specific. But on Android 10 `svc data enable|disable` doesn't work even with root (neither with UID 2000 alone). It works only on `adb shell`. So there have some changes occured at API level (it's not even SELinux, I checked). But I haven't looked into it deeply yet.

Comment: @IrfanLatif via ADB Wifi aeroplane mode is working rather nicely.  I took it on a test ride earlier today.  So it looks like the solution might be to avoid rebooting on the road (though I may have a backup phone and there may be ways to run ADB shell on that over OTG - I'm still reading)